auto-py-to-exe: "No module named '_jpype'"
I want to create an exe File with auto-py-to-exe but I alway get the follwing error:
File "C:\Users\robin\output\startup\_internal\jpype\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _jpype
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_jpype'

I added _jpype to the hidden imports but it can not find the module.
Is there a way to solve this?

maybe check source code for jpype - it may use some other elements (like C/C++ libraries or Java module) which you have to add manually.
